# T-SQL solution for GYM trainers TimeTable and session booking

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have four  tables
**tblEmployees**

```
EmployeeID  Name    
1   Zahiz
2   Nigon
3   Jimian
4   Ash
5   Dani
```

**tblMembers**

```
MemberNo    FirstName
1   Saleem
2   Jamil
3   Jazi
4   funa
5   Jhon
6   Moum
```

**RefSessions**

```
SessionID   StartTime   EndTime
1   0701    0730
2   0731    0800
3   0801    0830
4   0831    0900
5   0901    0930
6   0931    1000
7   1001    1030
8   1031    1100
9   1101    1130
10  1131    1200
11  1201    1230
12  1231    1300
13  1301    1330
14  1331    1400
15  1401    1430
16  1431    1500
17  1501    1530
18  1531    1600
19  1601    1630
20  1631    1700
21  1701    1730
22  1731    1800
23  1801    1830
24  1831    1900
25  1901    1930
26  1931    2000
27  2001    2030
28  2031    2100
```

**tblBookSession**

```
BookingID   SessionID   EmployeeID  MemberNo    SessionDate
1   15  2   3   2012-09-30 
2   16  2   3   2012-09-30 
3   1   3   4   2012-10-03
4   2   3   4   2012-10-03
5   3   3   4   2012-10-03
6   4   3   4   2012-10-03
```

[I am looking for a t-sql query resulting in said  form  against a specific date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHOZP.png)

Its actually booking of time slot of trainers in a gym and displaying In the  form of date wise report

Answer (score 3):

You will need to perform a [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). There are two ways to do this with PIVOT, either a Static Pivot where you code the columns to transform or a Dynamic Pivot which determines the columns at execution.

A Static Pivot, you will need to hard-code the values:

```
select name,
   IsNull([701-730], '') [701-730],
   IsNull([731-800], '') [731-800],
   IsNull([801-830], '') [801-830],
   IsNull([831-900], '') [831-900]
from
(
  select e.name,
    cast(e.starttime as varchar(10))+'-'
      +cast(e.endtime as varchar(10)) Session,
    m.FirstName
  from
  (
    select *
    from tblEmployees e
    cross apply RefSessions
  ) e
  left join tblBookSession b
    on e.EmployeeID = b.EmployeeID
    and e.sessionid = b.sessionid
  left join tblMembers m
    on b.MemberNo = m.MemberNo
) x
pivot
(
  max(FirstName)
  for session in ([701-730], [731-800], [801-830], [831-900]) -- additional sessions here
)p
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/00b75/22)

If you have many values to transform into columns or an unknown number of values, then you will want to use a dynamic sql version of the `PIVOT`:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsPivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' 
                      + QUOTENAME(cast(starttime as varchar(10))
                                  +'-'+cast(endtime as varchar(10))) 
                    from RefSessions
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')



select @colsPivot = STUFF((SELECT ', IsNull(' 
                      + QUOTENAME(cast(starttime as varchar(10))
                          +'-'+cast(endtime as varchar(10))) +', '''') as [' +
                           cast(starttime as varchar(10))
                                  +'-'+cast(endtime as varchar(10)) + ']'
                    from RefSessions
                    group by SessionID, starttime, endtime
                    order by SessionID 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')



set @query = 'SELECT name, ' + @colsPivot + ' from 
             (
                  select e.name,
                    cast(starttime as varchar(10))+''-''
                      +cast(endtime as varchar(10)) Session,
                    m.FirstName
                  from
                  (
                    select *
                    from tblEmployees e
                    cross apply RefSessions
                  ) e
                  left join tblBookSession b
                    on e.EmployeeID = b.EmployeeID
                    and e.sessionid = b.sessionid
                  left join tblMembers m
                    on b.MemberNo = m.MemberNo
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(FirstName)
                for Session in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/85e05/38)